# Word macro to find profanity, and create a list of occurences

Tags: vba, list, search, ms-word

I have TV scripts that occasionally have profanities in them that must be brought to the attention of a third party. I built a macro that searches for specific words, temporarily disfigures them so they aren't repeatedly found again, and lists them, and the times at which they occur in the macro... Problem: Without even running it, I KNOW it will only find the first instance of the word... Sometimes they say the same word 20 times...  I need to list each occurence and the time code. Not replace, or highlight.. just list the word. What I have so far... Any help is appreciated.

```
        Sub Macro7()
'
' Macro7 Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "dog"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Copy

    ' places cursor inside the word so I can disfigure it

    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

    ' xxx1 temporarily disfigures the word so it isn't re-found over and over

    Selection.TypeText Text:="xxx1"

    ' goes to end of document and pastes the word there,
    ' to be joined by the matching timecode to be found next

    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    ' returns to last instance of word and finds time code
    ' immediately preceeding it

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "xxx1"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find

        'this is finding the time code

        .Text = "^?^?:^?^?:^?^?:^?^?"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = False
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute

    ' copies the time code value and goes to bottom of document
    ' to paste it with the word previously found

    Selection.Copy
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

    ' returns to the word just found

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "xxx1"
        .Forward = False
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1


    ' begins the process for the next word "cat"

     Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "cat"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Copy

    ' places cursor inside the word so I can disfigure it
    ' etc etc etc

End Sub
```

Comment: Since no one has taken a shot at my question, I assume it's not phrased clearly enough. An example of what content it searches through would be:  01:03:05:22       Blah blah blah profanity and blah blah blah blah blah. next line down  01:09:44:22  blah blah blah blah blah profanity (I used 'dog' and 'cat') more blah blah blah of speaking from script

Comment: No one can help? Really?

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier if you put the content into Excel. For example, assuming each time code and associated text is in a single CELL in column A, on Sheet1, the following macro will produce a list in column J of all time codes where the specified TARGET appears. The macro could be expanded to find additional targets and output the list of those associated time codes into a different column.

```
Sub FindTarget()
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISERROR(IF(SEARCH(""TARGET"",RC[-2]),""TRUE"",""FALSE"")),"""",IF(SEARCH(""TARGET"",RC[-2]),""TRUE"",""FALSE""))"
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=""true"",LEFT(RC[-3],8),"""")"
    Range("C1:D1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:D9999"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("J1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("J1:J9999")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Columns("C:D").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("K1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This macro makes no sense at all... I placed a profanity word in C1, and benign words in C4, C7, etc...Placed timed codes in A1, A4, A7... changed the word TARGET in your macro, to a matching profanity, and ran the macro.. It simply wipes out everything in column C....Places nothing in column J... I need this to work in WORD anyway...so....thanks for trying. but the 2nd through 4th lines don't appear to do anything related to my task.

Comment: @CJG To make things easy I made the macro so the ENTIRE line (time code and associated text) goes in ONE SINGLE CELL in the A column. Assuming each time code/associated text is separated by paragraphs, this is how it will directly paste into Excel from Word.I updated my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: While double-checking the macro worked I realized that the find() function is case sensitive. Changed it to search() which is case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Do the words have to stay within the doc or can they be copied/pasted into a new word doc?